# MySQL query find specific column data but exclude if it contains another specific column data (same column)

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to change the post_status in a wordpress database based on 2 things. First all posts must have term_taxonomy_id = 2902 and then exclude the posts that also have term_taxonomy_id = 3152

This is the database structure:

**Table wpsite_posts**

```
   Column ID
   Column post_status
```

**Table wpsite_term_relationships**

```
   Column object_id
   Column term_taxonomy_id
```

Column **ID** and Column **Object ID** contains the data that match between these 2 tables.. Here are some test queries...

```
SELECT *
FROM wpsite_posts
WHERE ID IN (SELECT object_id
            FROM wpsite_term_relationships
            WHERE term_taxonomy_id = 2902
                AND NOT term_taxonomy_id = 3152);
```

This query, returns all posts with term_taxonomy_id 2902 and fails to ignore posts which also have term_taxonomy_id 3152.

```
SELECT *
FROM wpsite_posts
WHERE ID IN (SELECT object_id
            FROM wpsite_term_relationships
            WHERE term_taxonomy_id = 2902
                AND term_taxonomy_id NOT IN (3152));
```

This query, returns all posts with term_taxonomy_id 2902 and fails to ignore posts which also have term_taxonomy_id 3152.

```
SELECT *
FROM wpsite_posts
WHERE ID IN (SELECT object_id
            FROM wpsite_term_relationships
            WHERE term_taxonomy_id NOT IN (3152)
                AND term_taxonomy_id = '2902');
```

This query, returns all posts with term_taxonomy_id 2902 and fails to ignore posts which also have term_taxonomy_id 3152.

A live query would look something like this....

```
UPDATE wpsite_posts
SET post_status = 'private'
WHERE ID IN (SELECT object_id
             FROM wpsite_term_relationships
             WHERE term_taxonomy_id = 2902
AND NOT term_taxonomy_id = 3152);
```

This does not work, this lists all posts with term_taxonomy_id 2902 even though they also have term_taxonomy_id 3152.

What way should i go about this?

Comment: try this `SELECT *
FROM wpsite_posts
WHERE ID IN (SELECT object_id
            FROM wpsite_term_relationships
            WHERE term_taxonomy_id = 2902
                AND term_taxonomy_id != 3152);`

Comment: good attempt, didn't work though

Comment: If term_taxonomy_id=2902 than by definition it is never 3152. So that doesnt make any sense. You need two `in` queries. The first in with 2902 and then the second not in 3152. `where id in (2902) and id not in (3152)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it in a single `IN` statement because all the records with `term_taxonomy_id=2902` wont have value `3152`. You need one list with positive object ids and a list with negative ids. Then you can include the first set and exclude the last.

```
SELECT * 
FROM wpsite_posts 
WHERE ID IN (
  SELECT object_id 
  FROM wpsite_term_relationships 
  WHERE term_taxonomy_id = 2902
)
AND ID NOT IN (
  SELECT object_id 
  FROM wpsite_term_relationships 
  WHERE term_taxonomy_id = 3152
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Select p.* FROM wpsite_posts p inner join  wpsite_term_relationships t1 on p.id=t1.object_id left join (select object_id,  term_taxonomy_id from wpsite_term_relationships where term_taxonomy_id = 3152) t2 on p.id=t2.object_id WHERE t1.term_taxonomy_id = 2902 and t2.term_taxonomy_id is null

Sorry for bad formatting, send by phone...

Comment: thanks but this returns nothing when i run the query.

Comment: I'm afraid, but I think you do not have any record which doesn't have both taxonomy id

Comment: Please do: Select count(*) FROM wpsite_posts p inner join wpsite_term_relationships t1 on p.id=t1.object_id WHERE t1.term_taxonomy_id = 2902; and compare the returned count to this: Select count(*) FROM wpsite_posts p inner join wpsite_term_relationships t1 on p.id=t1.object_id inner join wpsite_term_relationships t2 on p.id=t2.object_id WHERE t1.term_taxonomy_id = 2902 and t2.term_taxonomy_id = 3152

Comment: get sql syntax error, am i using a too old version of sql to use this query? * SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') FROM wpsite_posts p inner join wpsite_term_relationships' at line 1 */

Comment: Oh yes, stack overflow canceled the star in count(*)

Comment: I did a test of the select in my answer in this sqlfiddle playground and it is working well. I readlly think you do not have ant post with taxonomy 2902 not having 3152, too. See here: [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7f8035/1/0)

Comment: ok with your new formating the query runs, but it returns nothing. I do have content that has both 2902 and 3152, a correct query should only return 1 of those 2 this one returns none of the 2, my attempted queries on top returns both of them.